# How to compute the chord length of an ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections

How do I calculate the chord length of ellipse? I need to design a blade vane rotating inside an elliptical profile. The blade is supposed to be in contact with ellipse with a maximum clearance of $0.4\ mm$.

The chord length (i.e., the blade vane) will obviously vary along the ellipse.

I need to find a way to fix the minor axis to major axis ratio of the ellipse such that, when the blade is fixed, it won't exceed a clearance of $.4\ mm$.

Thanks!

Comment: If the blade rotates around the center of the ellipse, it has to be a bit shorter than the minor axis. Its ends won't be near the ellipse as it rotates, only near as it goes by the minor axis. The ratio of major to minor axis makes no difference to how long the blade can be. Just when that ratio is large the blade will be far from the ellipse when it goes by the major axis.

Comment: So, if I'm picturing this correctly, the "profile" (the space in which the vane is rotating) will have to be almost circular, right? Because the 0.4mm is a *maximum* clearance, so the tip of the blade will be almost touching the profile throughout the 360 degrees of its rotation.

Comment: Its almost circular but it still is an ellipse.

Comment: Also, the blade is not going to rotate about the ellipse's center. It is placed at an eccentric point.
Could anyone say how could this formulation be made.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Is there a way to find out the point on the ellipse along its minor axis such that, if a chord is drawn through that point equals to the length of minor axis?

Comment: Is your blade an object of fixed length rotating about a fixed point? If so, it sweeps out a circular area centered at the fixed point of the blade. By allowing the clearance to vary between $0$ and $0.4$ mm as the blade rotates, you can draw a non-concentric ellipse around the circle, but it will still have to be within $0.4$ mm of the circle at all points. It sounds like you're looking for something different from that, but it's very unclear what that might be.

Comment: A figure would be welcome.

Comment: @Anisa your blade vane design completed? can you give a sketch?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/an-analytic-solution-for-ellipse-and-line-intersection/

Basic idea: starting from writing down the formula for an ellipse:

$$(\dfrac{x}{a})^2 + (\dfrac{y}{b})^2 = 1$$

where $a$ is the semi-major axis, $b$ is the semi-minor axis. Then write down the formula for a line

$$y_1 = m \times x_1 + b$$

Where

$$m = \dfrac{y_2-y}{x_2-x}$$

(We are deriving the eqn of a line given two points).

Solve for the y-intercept, $b$ in terms of $x_1$ and $y_1$, then plug that back into the line equation. Finally, represent $y$ using $x$ in the line formula, then replace $y$ in the ellipse formula using the representation you got from line. In that case you can solve the $x$ for two intersections.